# Django custom User model vs. profile model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django 1.5 app that currently has 2 different models for every user: the built-in `User` model, and my own `MyUser` model which contains information that is also used in the authentication process.

I would like to merge these two models into one, or at least reference one from the other.

If I was to build a new app, I would do `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'`, but [according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), changing the user model makes many changes to the DB and might be difficult to migrate in an existing app.

On the other end, the docs also say that a referenced profile model should only `store non-auth related information about a site user`.

**So my question is**: in an existing app, what is the preferred way to merge my custom user model with the built-in `User` model?

Comment: What do you mean by "reference one from the other"? Do they not already have a relationship, eg OneToOneField?

Comment: No they don't. `MyUser` is currently independent from the `User` model, and that what's I would like to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrating `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` isn't trivial, but definitely possible:

See http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/08/07/migrating-custom-user-model-django/ for a detailed walkthrough of the process.

If you are willing to take the time to do this now, it can be a significant step in decreasing technical debt in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use [one-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relation in django. The model can be like:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
     dj_user= models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Comment: That's what the docs say. However it also says that in this case `CustomUser` should only store non-auth data. I wonder why...

Comment: That means, you have to store username and password in `User`

Comment: Yeah but my app enables authentication not only by username and password, so there are more authentication related data in my custom user model.

Comment: Well, User model stores lots of info like first_name, last_name, email etc. according to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users you will only require username and password to authenticate(if you use django auth system), other related information can be stored in your custom model's fields. :) .

Comment: Thanks ruddra. The thing is that I have some custom authentication backends that require other data then username and password, and this data is stored in the custom user model.